# Spring MVC 3.2 and JSON ObjectMapper issue

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have recently upgraded my Spring version to 3.2.0 from 3.1.2. I find that that JSON properties like wrap root element, prevent null values that are defined in ObjectMapper are not working anymore.

Here is the code snippet

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" /> 
    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" /> 
    <property name="mediaTypes" >
        <value>
            json=application/json
            xml=application/xml
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and the JSON converter

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
   <property name="objectMapper" ref="customJacksonObjectMapper"/>  
   <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

Object mapper code

```
public class CustomJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CustomJacksonObjectMapper() {
    super();
    final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();

    this.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    this.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

    this.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES, false);

    this.setDeserializationConfig(this.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector));
    this.setSerializationConfig(this.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector));

   }
}
```

Jackson version

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

What could be the issue? Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `CustomJacksonObjectMapper` is used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I could not determine why the code in question is not working, but I could reproduce the problem. This answer does provide an alternate approach that works for me.*

It *could* be a bug, as I can reproduce the problem with both with explicit config:

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.demo.CustomJacksonObjectMapper"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
   <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
   <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

and via the *mvc:message-converter*:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

where both give me `{"foo":null,"bar":"bar"}` when using the example class

**Demo.java**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class Data {
    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public Dummy dataIndex() {
        return new Dummy();
    }

    public class Dummy {
        String foo = null;
        @JsonProperty
        public String foo() {
            return foo;
        }
        String bar = "bar";
        @JsonProperty
        public String bar() {
            return bar;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would have thought the *mvc:message-converter* method would work, only because I have seen issues overriding the default bean registration that `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` performs (see [Web MVC Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)) and using the nested configuration is preferred(?).

Maybe the [Jackson 2 support](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.2.html#new-in-3.2-webmvc-jackson-json) has caused some backwards compatibility issues with Jackson 1?

However, switching to the [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) (supported in Spring 3.1.2 and Spring 3.2), I *am* able to alter the ObjectMapper configuration to not write null values and wrap the JSON output... **but** only when using the config inside the `<mvc:message-converters/>`!

I get `{"Dummy":{"bar":"bar"}}` with the following changes:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**CustomJacksonObjectMapper.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.*;

public class CustomJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

public CustomJacksonObjectMapper() {
    super();
    this.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    this.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
   }
}
```

**Demo.java** switch to new package structure for Jackson 2

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

**demo-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Lastly, according to the [`SerializationConfig.Feature`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.Feature.html#WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES) documentation, `WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES` feature is deprecated < v2.0 and you should be using `SerializationConfig.setSerializationInclusion()` anyway. I assume this is why the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` exists in your code. In Jackson >= v2.0, it has been removed, hence the code change in the **CustomJacksonObjectMapper.java** example.

[Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configurating-objectmapper-in-spring) proposes an alternate solution.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time post the reply in a short time. that worked for me. Also a special thanks to stackoverflow.com for providing this wonderful platform for sharing these things and its about time for me to contribute in ways I can ....

Comment: Happy to help :-) If anyone can determine why it is broken for Jackson 1, I'd be very interested to know why! If I had the time I would try and debug Spring a bit more.

Comment: @andyb I've tried this solution but I'm getting 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.CustomJacksonObjectMapper' exception when I try to start up Tomcat.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like the `CustomJacksonObjectMapper.java` example class is not in a `com.demo` package. I don't have this src any more but I can try to recreate it if you are still having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this one is an old post, I phased a similar (maybe even the same?) problem. I tracked it down to the following issue (and this might help others):

- An extra library that was added has a transient dependency on Jackson 2.x
- So far we had a dependency on Jackson 1.x
- Between Jackson 1.x and Jackson 2.x the namespace was changed to avoid conflicts
- Sprint started to pick up the newer (2.x) version
- The annotation was still to the old (1.x) version

To solve the issue I can either:

1. remove the 2.x version again
2. Upgrade the annotation to the 2.x version
3. Add an extra annotation to also cover the 2.x version

In my case I went for solution 3, since we require the two different versions and the additional annotation didn't add a big overhead.