# Jackson : NoSuchMethodError for org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.withAnnotationIntrospector

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, nosuchmethoderror

I am using Spring MVC 3.2 with Jackson.Everything works fine when I was working on Ubuntu 12.04.
But our deployment server has Cent OS 6.So while deploying My project copy on server following stacktrace is coming and application is failed to get deployed.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.withAnnotationIntrospector(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/AnnotationIntrospector;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig;
    at com.domain.atmosphere.JaxbJacksonObjectMapper.<init>(JaxbJacksonObjectMapper.java:26)
    at com.controller.BroadCastingController.pollForNewArrival(BroadCastingController.java:132)
    at com.controller.BroadCastingController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$379dc3e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.hcdc.coedp.safe.controller.BroadCastingController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8be92c05.pollForNewArrival(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Following are the jars that I am using for jackson support.

```
  jackson-annotations-2.0.4.jar:
  jackson-databind-2.0.4.jar:
  jackson-xc-1.9.11.jar:
  jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.8.jar:
  jackson-core-2.0.4.jar:
  jackson-core-asl-1.9.8.jar
```

And this is my custom `JaxbJacksonObjectMapper`

```
public class JaxbJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {


    public JaxbJacksonObjectMapper() {
        final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
        super.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        super.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        this.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS.getDefaultPropertyName());
    }

}
```

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094180/jackson-objectmapper-constructor-throws-nosuchmethod) answer that this is a problem of version incompatibility.So if that's the case If any one could tell me the right version to be used with Spring MVC 3.2 I will be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the *-asl jar, they are from older versions. As to -xc I don't know what it is supposed to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have libraries from different packages and diferent versions.

Package: **com.fasterxml.jackson.core**

- Libraries in your project from this package:

  - jackson-annotations-2.0.4.jar:
  - jackson-databind-2.0.4.jar:
  - jackson-core-2.0.4.jar:

Package: **org.codehaus.jackson**

- Libraries in your project from this package:

  - jackson-xc-1.9.11.jar:
  - jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.8.jar
  - jackson-core-asl-1.9.8.jar

Jackson changed the name of the package in the version 2 to **com.fasterxml.jackson.core**, so you should remove all your libraries from previous version 1 in order to avoid incompatibilites problems.

Here in this other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333709/spring-mvc-3-2-and-json-objectmapper-issue) they had problems with version 1 and Spring 3, maybe it could add more information about your problem and possible changes you will have to do.