# Spring @Autowired doesn't inject dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following class declaring the `ProjectConfig` bean

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "House")
public class ProjectConfig{

    private List<HouseTemplate> templates;

    // getters and setters
}
```

in a class annotated with `@Service` I autowire this bean correctly and I'm able to get the `templates` list from it and do whatever I want:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceDefault{

    @Autowired
    private ProjectConfig config;
```

however in another class I'm not able to autowire this dependency:

```
@Component
public class HouseTemplateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<HouseTemplate>{


    @Autowired
    private ProjectConfig config;


    @Override
    public HouseTemplate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        logger.info("projectConfig is {}", config);
    }
```

and of course in the logs I see: `projectConfig is null`.

`HouseTemplateDeserializer` is annotated with `@Component` and is in a package that I know is getting scanned by spring because other beans are defined in the same package and everything works there.

What am I missing?

```
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>

<artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: `HouseTemplateDeserializer` isn't managed by Spring but by Jackson. Jackson doesn't know how to handle `@Autowired`. The `@Component` doesn't help here as the Spring created instance isn't the one that is going to be used by Jackson.

Comment: Damn, so I can't use the spring context in classes managed by Jackson? Is there a workaround?

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have any source/documentation for this type of behaviour? What defines a class as being managed by jackson? Do you have a book on jackson that you would recommend? thanks

Comment: Actually there is support in Spring for this. Using the `SpringHandlerInstantiator`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198777/2696260 for the configuration.

Comment: @Archibald for managed classes (like jackson) you can explicitly create a bean for this class using `@Bean` annotation

Comment: @Vihar so you're saying that changing `@Component` to `@Bean` on top of my `HouseTemplateDeserializer` class would be enough to fix it?

Comment: NO it is explicitly for classes which are not managed by us, for this usecase I feel there is some issue with the package under which these classes are present and that might be the reason these classes are not picked up by Spring for dependency Injection

Comment: @Vihar what about using `@Configurable` instead of `@Component` on top of my deserializer?

Comment: Using `@Bean` nor `@Configuration` won't work. `@Configurable` could work but that would require AspectJ loadtime or compile timeweaving and a java agent setup. I already pointed you to [this answer](stackoverflow.com/a/69198777/2696260) which should solve your issue using the `SpringHandlerInstantiator` to integrate Jackson serializers with Spring.

Comment: @Vihar the instance used by Jackson is not the Spring one, it is managed by Spring but Jackson doesn't use that one.

Comment: @Archibald another thing you could try is to pass ProjectConfig in a constructor of HouseTemplateSerializer and then you will instanciate it like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104435/how-do-i-use-jackson-json-parsing-in-a-spring-project-without-any-annotations

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm having troubles understanding the logic of the answer you suggested. I'm going to answer my question with a possible implementation and some doubts. I'd like to receive your opinion.