# How to customise the Jackson JSON mapper implicitly used by Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot (1.2.1), in a similar fashion as in their [Building a RESTful Web Service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) tutorial:

```java
@RestController
public class EventController {
   @RequestMapping("/events/all")
   EventList events() {
       return proxyService.getAllEvents();
   }
}
```

So above, Spring MVC implicitly uses Jackson for serialising my `EventList` object into JSON.

But I want to do some simple customisations to the JSON format, such as:

```java
setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Question is, **what is the simplest way to customise the implicit JSON mapper?**

I tried the approach in **[this blog post](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html)**, creating a CustomObjectMapper  and so on, but the step 3, "Register classes in the Spring context", fails:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'jacksonFix': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Could not autowire method: public void com.acme.project.JacksonFix.setAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter(org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter); 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
  No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter]   
  found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

It looks like those instructions are for older versions of Spring MVC, while I'm looking for a simple way to get this working with latest Spring Boot.

Comment: Do you have this Annotation inserted?: @SuppressWarnings({"SpringJavaAutowiringInspection"})

Comment: Notice that if you are using Spring Web as well you will need to tell it manually to use this ObjectMapper otherwise it will create it own instance which will not be configured. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can configure property inclusion, and numerous other settings, via `application.properties`:

```properties
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

There's a table in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) that lists all of the properties that can be used.

If you want more control, you can also customize Spring Boot's configuration programatically using a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` bean, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper):

> The context’s `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` can be customized by one or more `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` beans. Such customizer beans can be ordered (Boot’s own customizer has an order of 0), letting additional customization be applied both before and after Boot’s customization.

Lastly, if you don't want any of Boot's configuration and want to take complete control over how the `ObjectMapper` is configured, declare your own `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean:

```java
@Bean
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    // Configure the builder to suit your needs
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: Alright, this seems to work. Where would you put such a method? Perhaps in a main Application class (with `@ComponentScan`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` etc)?

Comment: Yes. This method can go in any `@Configuration` class in your app. The main `Application` class is a good place for it.

Comment: Important note: The Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder class is part of the spring-web component and was added in version 4.1.1.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson With this configuration, you can't use anymore Spring boot auto-configuration for Jackson isn't it ?

Comment: @herau Correct. If you're happy using a milestone, Spring Boot 1.3 adds support for configuring serialisation inclusion via application.properties: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/1dcf18b16ebbacfdcad9259f808d4949f0668181

Comment: @Deprecated setSerializationInclusion

Comment: Deprecated: ObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion was deprecated in Jackson 2.7 ... use https://stackoverflow.com/a/44137972/6785908  spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null instead

Comment: "If you're using an earlier version of Spring Boot" made me believe it wouldn't work with Spring Boot 2.0.1, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I am having a problem with this approach of configuring the ObjectMapper in Spring Boot. Spring Boot does its own configuration of the ObjectMapper with its own Serializers/Deserializers for e.g. LocalDateTime. When defining your own Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder you are loosing this Spring configuration.

Comment: There are more properties than just the six mentioned in the linked "How-to" guide.  A full list is available a the reference documentation [appendex](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-json) (currently eleven `spring.jackson.*` options are mentioned).

Answer (score 32):

I am answering bit late to this question, but someone, in future, might find this useful. The below approach, besides lots of other approaches, works best, and I personally think would better suit a web application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 ... other configurations

@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        builder.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        builder.serializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
        builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.createXmlMapper(true).build()));
    }
}
```

Comment: In recent version you must implement `WebMvcConfigurer`

Comment: yes, peoples, try this solution, I've tried to provide Bean for ObjectMapper, then Bean for Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder buy that didn't work and I still have no idea why. Appending coverter worked!

Answer (score 27):

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) states several ways to do this.

> If you want to replace the default `ObjectMapper` completely, define a `@Bean` of that type and mark it as `@Primary`.
>
> Defining a `@Bean` of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` will allow you to customize both default `ObjectMapper` and `XmlMapper` (used in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` respectively).

Comment: How to do the same without replacing the default `ObjectMapper` ? I mean keeping the default as well a custom.

Answer (score 24):

A lot of things can configured in applicationproperties. Unfortunately this feature only in Version 1.3, but you can add in a Config-Class

```
@Autowired(required = true)
public void configureJackson(ObjectMapper jackson2ObjectMapper) {
    jackson2ObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
}
```

[UPDATE: You must work on the ObjectMapper because the `build()`-method is called before the config is runs.]

Comment: That was the solution that saved my day. Except I did add this method to the REST controller itself, rather than to the configuration class.

Answer (score 14):

You can add a following method inside your bootstrap class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);

    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());

    return objectMapper;
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me using Boot 2.1.3. The spring.jackson properties had no effect.

Answer (score 11):

`spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non_null` used to work for us

But when we upgraded spring boot version to 1.4.2.RELEASE or higher, it stopped working.

Now, another property `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` is doing the magic.

in fact, `serialization-inclusion` is deprecated. This is what my intellij throws at me.

> Deprecated: ObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion was deprecated in
>   Jackson 2.7

**So, start using `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` instead**

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon another solution, which is quite nice.

Basically, only do [step 2 from the blog posted mentioned](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html), and define a custom ObjectMapper as a Spring `@Component`. (Things started working when I just *removed* all the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter stuff from step 3.)

```
@Component
@Primary
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL); 
        configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); 
    }
}
```

Works as long as the component is in a package scanned by Spring. (Using `@Primary` is not mandatory in my case, but why not make things explicit.)

For me there are two benefits compared to the other approach:

- This is simpler; I can just extend a class from Jackson and don't need to know about highly Spring-specific stuff like `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`.
- I want to use the same Jackson configs for deserialising JSON in another part of my app, and this way it's very simple: `new CustomObjectMapper()` instead of  `new ObjectMapper()`.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that your custom configuration won't be applied to any `ObjectMapper` instances that are created or configured by Spring Boot.

Comment: Hmm, the custom config *is* used for the implicit serialisation in `@RestController` classes which currently suffices for me. (So you mean those instances are created by Spring MVC, not Spring Boot?) But if I run into other cases where ObjectMappers need to be instantiated, I'll keep the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder approach in mind!

Answer (score 5):

When I tried to make ObjectMapper primary in spring boot 2.0.6 I got errors
So I modified the one that spring boot created for me

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48519868/255139

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
ObjectMapper mapper;

@PostConstruct
public ObjectMapper configureMapper() {
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);

    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS, true);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
    module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The right way to add further configurations to the Spring Boot peconfigured ObjectMapper is to define a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer. Else you are overwriting Springs configuration, which you do not want to lose.

```
 @Configuration
public class MyJacksonConfigurer implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        builder.deserializerByType(LocalDate.class, new MyOwnJsonLocalDateTimeDeserializer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution described above with :

**spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non_null**

To only work starting at the 1.4.0.RELEASE version of spring boot.  In all other cases the config is ignored.

I verified this by experimenting with a modification of the spring boot sample "spring-boot-sample-jersey"

Answer (score 1):

I've seen numerous questions regarding this issue. This is what worked for me in Spring Boot version 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT.

I created a configuration, MapperConfigs, created a objectMapper bean, annotated primary as the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M3/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html) says

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class MapperConfigs {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        log.info("Object mapper overrides ");
        return JsonMapper.builder()
                .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I then @Autowired objectMapper. See below:

```
@Service
public class GenerateRequestUniqueID {
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question asking for Spring boot, but I believe lot of people looking for how to do this in non Spring boot, like me searching almost whole day.

Above Spring 4, there is no need to configure `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` if you only intend to configure `ObjectMapper`.

You just need to do:

```
public class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4219938065516862637L;

    public MyObjectMapper() {
        super();
        enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    }       
}
```

And in your Spring configuration, create this bean:

```
@Bean 
public MyObjectMapper myObjectMapper() {        
    return new MyObjectMapper();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the default one and add your custom converter:**

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
//        Remove the default MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
        converters.removeIf(converter -> {
            String converterName = converter.getClass().getSimpleName();
            return converterName.equals("MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter");
        });
//        Add your custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converters.add(converter);
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Please don't use configureMessageConverters() instead of extendMessageConverters() from WebMvcConfigurer because configure method will remove all the existing converters which will be installed by default.

Hope it will help someone like me who has wasted some hours debugging the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to customize Jackson `ObjectMapper`:-

1. Override the default behavior of auto-configured `ObjectMapper` by Spring Boot
2. Overwrite the `ObjectMapper` to have a complete control

##### Override ObjectMapper

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomJacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                .configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true)
                .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false)
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
                .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true)
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }
}
```

##### Overwrite ObjectMapper

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomJacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                .configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true)
                .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false)
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
                .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    }
}
```

source: https://codingnconcepts.com/spring-boot/customize-jackson-json-mapper/