# Why am I getting 403 forbidden error while accessing swagger ui from browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger

This is my SecurityConfig class. I have whitelisted several endpoints using spring security but still getting 403 forbidden error when accessing swagger ui from browser. /auth/login and /auth/signup endpoints are working fine.

```
package com.navyug.security.authn.config;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import com.navyug.security.authn.service.UserServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = { "/v2/api-docs", "/v3/api-docs", "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/**", "/api-docs.yaml", "/ws",
            "auth/login", "auth/signup", "/", "/*.js", "/*.ico", "/*.json", "/*.png", "/*.jpg", "/*.txt*", "/*.css" };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(configurer -> configurer.requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults()).csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

This is my application.properties file.

```
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.with-credentials=false
```

I am using spring boot 3.1.4 and SpringDoc OpenAPI Starter WebMVC UI 2.2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just change `/v3/api-docs` to `/v3/api-docs/**` in your `AUTH_WHITELIST` it is going to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger UI empty and gives 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567900/swagger-ui-empty-and-gives-403)

Answer (score 0):

first after running your application check your services endpoints. there is mappings in intellij idea ide > services > your service > actuator > mappings. check swagger endpoints and create your security white list.

[image]