# Unable to find OpenApiResourceNotFoundException in springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

Unable to find OpenApiResourceNotFoundException class in springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui
I removed the dependency springdoc-openapi-ui and added the latest springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui

But I get error unable to find OpenApiResourceNotFoundException

Does OpenApiResourceNotFoundException is renamed in latest versions..
if yes, anyone please share the new class name along with the import

Thanks

I checked in google and githup , but it didnt help me much

Checked this so

[SpringDoc openAPI tool not scanning for APIs in Spring Boot Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921858/springdoc-openapi-tool-not-scanning-for-apis-in-spring-boot-project)