# LocalDate is serialized as an array

Tags: arrays, json, spring-boot, jackson, localdate

I'm using springBoot to develop a REST APi. And i have a LocalDate field "firstDate" in the response model of a GET endpoint. But this LocalDate is serializable as an array in the response's json!

```
"firstDate": [
        2021,
        3,
        1
      ],
```

So for consuming this APi, i have to define this date in my DTO as an array! which is not good!
My reponse models of th API are generated with swagger so i can not use @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")

Can you help me please and tell me how to serialize LocalDate properly in this case ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have your tried this

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
return mapper;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure LocaldateTime in Spring Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365917/configure-localdatetime-in-spring-rest-api)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)

Answer (score 4):

My dates defined as LocalDateTime were been serializaded as an array like this:

```
"timestamp": [
    2023,
    2,
    15,
    10,
    30,
    45,
    732425200
],
```

So here is what I did in my WebConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  // other configs

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(
        new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .dateFormat(new StdDateFormat())
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .build()));
  }

}
```

Now everything is good again:

```
"timestamp": "2023-02-15T10:32:06.5170689",
```

Hope it's been helpful. Some topics that helped me achieve that:

[Configure LocaldateTime in Spring Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365917/configure-localdatetime-in-spring-rest-api/75460597#75460597)

[How to customise the Jackson JSON mapper implicitly used by Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot)

[Can't serialize java.time.LocalDate as a String with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952269/cant-serialize-java-time-localdate-as-a-string-with-jackson)

Answer (score 2):

I think this WebConfig.class is unnecessary. You could try something like that in your field firstDate:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate firstDate;
```

There's no make sense define the field as an array in DTO because of the swagger config

Comment: You don't seem to have understood the question. They are serialising a java LocalDate object, not an array.
And it is bad practice to put repeated boilerplate like `@JsonFormat` on every date when those classes may need to be used in another application that talks a different format.

Answer (score 1):

Setting deserializer and serializers for the date fields will solve the problem:

```java
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDate issueDate;
```

use `LocalDateTimeSerializer` for `LocalDateTime` fields