# Prettify (or not) the response depending on the request with Jackson and Spring boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I am using Spring boot, Spring MVC and Jackson. I am writing a RESTful API and one of the requirements is to prettify the response (json) if only the request contains the parameter `prettify`.

For example, `GET /examples/1` must answer with: `{"id":1,"name":"example"}`, and `GET /examples/1?prettify` with:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "example"
}
```

I know I can define my own `ObjectMapper` but I cannot make it depending on the request. I can set `spring.jackson.serialization.INDENT_OUTPUT` to `true` but I cannot display a response **not** prettified.

Does someone have an idea about this?

Comment: Just a "loud thinking" but what I would try is to inject `Jackson2ObjectMapper` somewhere in your REST API controller, and then call its method `indentOutput (boolean)` depending on request. I believe that this topic may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot

Comment: Problem is, I can inject a new Jackson2ObjectMapper but, after the injection (done when the application starts), I do not see a way to "inject" the request in the Jackson2ObjectMapper

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've done it.

So, the way to do it, is to use injected Jackson2ObjectMapper to manually serialize response :)

Lets look on simple main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.indentOutput(true);
        return builder;
     }
}
```

Some rest controller class:

```
@RestController
public class TestRestController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestRestController.class);

    @Autowired
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testendpoint/{somevalue}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String customersLastVisit(@PathVariable(value = "somevalue") Integer number,
            @RequestParam(value = "pretify", defaultValue = "false") Boolean pretify) throws JsonProcessingException {
        if (pretify) {
            LOGGER.info("Pretify response!");
            objectMapperBuilder.indentOutput(true);
        }
        else {
            objectMapperBuilder.indentOutput(false);
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapperBuilder.build();
        String jsonResponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(new TestDTO());
        return jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

And DTO class:

```
public class TestDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public TestDTO() {
        super();
        id = new Integer(1);
        name = new String("SomeName");
    }
    //getters, setters etc ...
}
```

http://localhost:8080/testendpoint/1 returns `{"id":1,"name":"SomeName"}`
while http://localhost:8080/testendpoint/1?pretify=true returns

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "SomeName"
}
```

**Edit:**
If you want to use it for every controller do like this:

```
public class PretifyingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PretifyingInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        String pretify = request.getParameter("pretify");
        Boolean isPretify = Boolean.parseBoolean(pretify);

        LOGGER.info("Should be pretified: " + isPretify);

        if (isPretify) {
            mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setPrettyPrint(true);
        }
        else {
            mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setPrettyPrint(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now add new interceptor:

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    @Bean
    PretifyingInterceptor pretifyingInterceptor() {
        return new PretifyingInterceptor();
    }

     @Override
        public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(pretifyingInterceptor())
                    .addPathPatterns("/**");
        }

}
```

And now controller can look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testendpoint/{somevalue}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody TestDTO customersLastVisit(@PathVariable(value = "somevalue") Integer number,
            @RequestParam(value = "pretify", defaultValue = "false") Boolean pretify) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new TestDTO();
    }
```

Edit2: To avoid some 'between-request shared state of Interceptor', define the Interceptor bean with scope `request`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: You can just autowire the ObjectMapper and use `writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()`.

Comment: So here we have a way to do it for one request. But we would like to do it for every requests, with an interceptor I suppose. I'm looking for override the Jackson interceptor but I haven't find a way yet.

Comment: @patrykos91 Thanks for your update. Looking at your answer, I suppose we will have some concurrency problems. For example: Thread A is stopped at the end of the method `preHandle` with `pretiffy=true`. Thread B does the whole job with `pretiffy=false`. Thread A ends the job: the result won't be pretiffied.
I think we need to reimplement the json serializer.

Comment: Not  necessarily. Better test it out before You start json serlializer reimplementation. I think it all depends on what is the scope for  `objectMapper` that is obtained by `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;`. If its scoped as `request` every request will have its own instance, and nothing will collide.

Comment: After a few benchmarks it seems you are right. There is no multithreading issue. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: EDIT : a few more benchmarks and it doesn't work good anymore. I am looking for a good way, I'll post my answer if I find it.

Comment: What precisely is wrong with my solution? Maybe I can help some more.