# @JsonProperty on class fields - getting duplicate fields in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a class Student with some fields. I wanted to give custom names for the JSON fields that get returned.

```
public class Student {


    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String mName;

    @JsonProperty("DOB")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date mBirthDate;

    @JsonProperty("SSN")
    private String mSocialSecurityNumber;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String mName, Date mBirthDate, String mSocialSecurityNumber) {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mBirthDate = mBirthDate;
        this.mSocialSecurityNumber = mSocialSecurityNumber;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return mBirthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date mBirthDate) {
        this.mBirthDate = mBirthDate;
    }

    public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
        return mSocialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public void setSocialSecurityNumber(String mSocialSecurityNumber) {
        this.mSocialSecurityNumber = mSocialSecurityNumber;
    }
}
```

My JSON output has both the raw field name (based on the getter name, e.g. getSocialSecurityNumber()), as well as the name specified in my `@JsonProperty` attributes.

It seems like if I move the @JsonProperty attributes to the getters, then I don't get the doubleup of the fields. Is there not a way I can do this by just having the annotations on the fields, which I feel is a little cleaner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to consider only the fields:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

---

In Spring Boot you can use [`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html) to configure the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {

    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            super.configure(objectMapper);
            objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
            objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with ObjectMapper -- not using it. This is happening all under the hood for me via Spring Boot 1.4.3

Comment: @StealthRabbi So you can use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. Let me provide you with an example.

Comment: Looks like I can manipulate the bean as shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot

Comment: This is helpfu. So, the default is presumbably PropertyAccessor.GETTER, which explains why that, without @JsonProperty tags, my JSON fields are 'name' and not 'mName'.