# Use custom jackson mapper on spring boot endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I want to use different jackson **ObjectMapper** instance ( instead of the one used on other mapped urls ) on endpoints derived from **AbstractEndpoints**.

To clarify the question, I don't want to change or customise the object mapper which is used by different urls from the ones derived from **AbstractEndpoints** ( like **HealtEndpoint**, **MetricsEndpoint**  ). I want to specifically inject new object mapper into management endpoints.

Comment: Does defining a custom `@Bean` not work for you? See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the default ObjectMapper completely, either define a @Bean of that type and mark it as @Primary, or, if you prefer the builder-based approach, define a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder @Bean. Note that in either case this will disable all auto-configuration of the `ObjectMapper.

If you provide any @Beans of type MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter then they will replace the default value in the MVC configuration. Also, a convenience bean is provided of type HttpMessageConverters (always available if you use the default MVC configuration) which has some useful methods to access the default and user-enhanced message converters.

**You can read the full topic in the documentation: 73.3 Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem unfortunately. As I added some extra information in my question, I need another object mapper bean for using on specifically just management endpoints derived from AbstractEndpoints.

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring Boot 1.5 you can customize the `ObjectMapper` the JMX endpoints are using but not in the way you want. As you can see for example in the [constructor of `EndpointMBean`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/jmx/EndpointMBean.java#L49) it takes an `ObjectMapper` as argument but without any [qualifiers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers). Hence it automatically uses the default `ObjectMapper` and there's nothing you can do about it except changing the original sources or rolling your own endpoints and adding the necessary qualifiers.

If you still want to use the default endpoints provided by Spring Boot, customize the default `ObjectMapper` according to your needs, create a second instance that matches the original configuration and add the qualifiers to use the second `ObjectMapper` in your own code. The [customization options for Jackson's `ObjectMapper` are described in the Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) and also discussed in [How to customise the Jackson JSON mapper implicitly used by Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot).