# Spring Boot Jackson and Data serialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller, json-serialization

In my Spring Boot application I use a following DTO with `@RestController`:

```
public abstract class ComparableQuery extends BaseQuery {

    private final Object value;

...

}
```

Everything works fine but when I use Spring `RestTemplate` and pass `java.util.Date` as `ComparableQuery.value` I see that Jackson serialize the date object into the following "magic" number:

```
"value":1009836000000
```

Right now I don't understand how the date object serialized into the `1009836000000` number representation and how to emulate it when I use for example AngularJS as a client of my back-end API. Please advise.

Comment: I think this is the value of your date and is represented in long. You can receive this value and format it by using simpledateformat or anything equivalent to desired format

Comment: How to prepare this value in AngularJS for example ?

Comment: does this property helps? `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: Nice question I need the answer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very similar problem as described in [this answer about `null` handling with jackson and spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324976/139595).

The corresponding configuration for date formatting in `application.properties` should look like:

```
spring.jackson.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```