# Spring Boot not using configured Jackson ObjectMapper with @EnableWebMvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I wanted to use a configured version of Jackson `ObjectMapper` in my project (ignoring null values and snake_case, also using some custom modules).

In my large project I wasn't able to get Spring MVC to actually use this mapper.

The build.gradle:

```groovy
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:${springBootVersion}")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")

  compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.8'
  compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.8'

  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
  name: Jackson test
jackson:
  property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
  default-property-inclusion: non_empty
debug: true
```

A container class:

```java
public class MyLocationEntity {
    public String nameAndSnake;
}
```

A config class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig {
}
```

And a controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = "application/json")
  public MyLocationEntity test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    MyLocationEntity location = new MyLocationEntity();
    location.nameAndSnake = "hello world";
    String expexted = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(location);
    return location;
  }
}
```

If I now look at the value of `expected` in the debugger it is `{"name_and_snake":"hello world"}`.
But if I let the controller run through the actual response is `{"nameAndSnake":"hello world"}`.

When I remove `@EnableWebMvc` it works. How can I use the configured mapper with MVC and not remove the rest of the autoconfiguration for Web MVC?

Comment: `@EnableWebMvc` disables the web auto configuration of Spring Boot. Which configured mapper are you talking about? What isn't working with the auto configured instance?

Comment: Why do you use EnableWebMvc?

Comment: @JBNizet this is just the demo project to show the error. In this project it doesn't do anything. In the larger project it is needed.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. Why is it needed in the larger project? EnableWebMvc **disables** web mvc autoconfiguration. It doesn't enable it. Read the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration

Comment: Ok I see. So basically if I `@EnableWebMvc` I disable the autoconfiguration and therefore my configuration done in the application.yml is not applied. <-- this would have been an answer and not "why do you want to use it"

Comment: M. Deinum did say almost exactly that, and you didn't believe him... But anyway, at least it made you read the documentation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800851/143918

Comment: Was the `jackson` property indented in your actual code, but not in the question due to a copy/paste error?  Since other issues aside, the example code is currently mistakenly configuring the `jackson.property-naming-strategy` property rather than the correct `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy` property (likewise for `default-property-inclusion`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not evident just from the Javadocs, but `@EnableWebMvc` disables the Spring Boot default web MVC auto configuration provided by [`WebMvcAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.html), including the use of the Jackson `ObjectMapper` bean configured by the `application.yml` properties.  Per the [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration):

> ### 9.4.7. Switch off the Default MVC Configuration
>
> The easiest way to take complete control over MVC configuration is to provide your own `@Configuration` with the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. Doing so leaves all MVC configuration in your hands.

Since `@EnableWebMvc` has the (likely surprising) behavior of disabling auto configuration, using this annotation may have unintended and undesirable side-effects.  A different approach may be more appropriate.

That being said, it is possible that the behavior of `@EnableWebMvc` is still desired.  To use `application.yml` properties in concert with the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, the MVC configuration must be manually configured to mimic the relevant disabled Spring Boot auto-configuration.  There are a few different possible approaches to this.

The first approach is to duplicate the Spring Boot configuration code from [`WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration.configureMessageConverters()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration.html).  This will replace the message converters — including the [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) containing the unconfigured `ObjectMapper` — with the ones that would have used with the default Spring Boot configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectProvider<HttpMessageConverters> messageConvertersProvider;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        this.messageConvertersProvider
                .ifAvailable((customConverters) -> converters.addAll(customConverters.getConverters()));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, rather than using the default Spring Boot list of message converters, it is possible to swap in just the `ObjectMapper` or `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` bean provided by Spring Boot (which have the `application.yml` properties applied):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.stream()
                .filter(c -> c instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                .map(c -> (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) c)
                .forEach(c -> c.setObjectMapper(objectMapper));

    }
}
```

or

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for (int i = 0; i < converters.size(); i++) {
            if (converters.get(i) instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                converters.set(i, mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```