# How to configure Jackson in spring boot application without overriding springs default setting in pure java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

In my spring boot application i am using Jackson to serialize objects by injecting the `ObjectMapper` where needed.
I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842962/447426
But this one creates a new mapper - with jacksons default settings.

On the other hand i found [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) in official docu. I didn't really understand. There is no example code.

So how to configure springs ObjectMapper on base of Spring's default object mapper?

This configuration should be active on "ObjectMapper" whereever injected.

Comment: You should use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` for this

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomBigDecimalDeserialization() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
               jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
               // Add your customization
               // jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToEnable(...)      
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

Because a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` is a functor, Java 8 enables more compact code:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomBigDecimalDeserialization() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            // Add your customization
            // builder.featuresToEnable(...)      
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to configure "features like         DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES
MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION in general? I saw many convenient methods on jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder but does this cover all?

Comment: just edited your post - with nearly the same :-) - thanks

Answer (score 5):

> On the other hand i found this in official docu. I didn't really understood. There is no example code.

It's just saying that you only need to set the correct properties in the `application.properties` file to enable or disable the various Jackson features.

```
spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=false
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false
```

Comment: That works fine for simple features, but not complex ones.