# Spring Boot configures two MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am having a problem with a newly created Spring Boot application. For some reason *something* is adding *two* `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instances to the return value processing of Spring Web MVC (I found this out using the debugger).
One of them uses the `ObjectMapper` instance I create via a `@Bean` method in my configuration class, the other one uses some random other instance. This 2nd `ObjectMapper` is therefor completely unconfigured and my `ObjectMapper` configurations are not applied to the JSON serialization used by `@ResponseBody`.

How can I stop this duplication? You can find all of my code below.

*Edit:* This problem is *not* related to my custom `ObjectMapper` bean. Even if I remove it (completely empty configuration except `@SpringBootApplication`), I still get *two* `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instances, one of which uses a completely unconfigured and unreachable (as far as I can tell) `ObjectMapper`.

*Edit²:* This is not an issue of duplicate beans. `ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType` returns only *one* instance for both `ObjectMapper` and `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` no matter if I create the `ObjectMapper` myself or let it be created by spring autoconfiguration.

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RC1'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
    }
}

group 'de.takeweiland.springtest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
}
```

**Configuration class**:

```
package main;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package main;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("**")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: just so you know, if you use the annotation RestController, it combines Controller & ResponseBody so you can just use RestController & omit ResponseBody.

Comment: Thanks, I know about that. However I was keeping this example to an absolute minimum to make it easier to figure out where this problem is coming from.

Comment: well. 1 annotation instead of 2 would be minimal... just sayin'

Comment: why you instantiate ObjectMapper class?

Comment: Because I want to configure the `ObjectMapper` by, for example, adding mixin annotations, etc.
Even if I take the alternative approach of just registering a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module` as a Spring `@Component`, which will automatically register it to the standard `ObjectMapper`, only _one_ of the created `ObjectMapper` instances will have those modules.

Comment: For customizing the objectmapper, don't create a new object Mapper in your application. Instead you can customize the objectmapper provided by spring. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519772/how-to-configure-jackson-in-spring-boot-application-without-overriding-springs-d/48519868#48519868

Comment: This way you can get rid of multiple Objectmapper issue

Comment: No, I cannot. Even if I remove my custom `ObjectMapper` bean (no configuration at all except `@SpringBootApplication`) I still get _two_ `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instances. One of them uses the `ObjectMapper` that is available via Spring DI, which is therefor configurable, the other uses _some other mapper_, which I do not know where it comes from.

Comment: Hmm, the problem can be that `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration` has a `@Primary @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ObjectMapper.class)` marked ObjectMapper. Check that your configuration is loaded before this autoconfiguration. If the name of second `ObjectMapper` bean is 'jacksonObjectMapper' - load a configuration before autoconfiguration. Also that mapper is marked as `@Primary` so it is injected with DI by default.

Comment: @BogdanOros Does that apply even if my configuration is completely empty (see above)? How can I load my configuration before said autoconfiguration?

Comment: Try to create a configuration class with that bean with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` annotation.

Comment: @BogdanOros That made absolutely no difference. I still get the two converters.

Comment: Try to mark you `ObjectMapper` with `@Primary` annotation and check which one is injected by DI. Also can you paste the second mappers name?

Comment: Please read the edit to my question. This even happens if I do not make my own `ObjectMapper` at all!
I also verified using `ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType`: There is only _one_ `ObjectMapper` in the IoC container (whether created by me or spring boot autoconfiguration). But there are _still_ two `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instances in the return value mapper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164267/discussion-between-bogdan-oros-and-diesieben07).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I have found the issue and it was simply an issue with my Jackson configuration not working as I thought it would.
Having two `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is not a problem.

Comment: So what was the misconfiguration on your side...? We are likely facing similar problem, but no solution is provided here :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of two jackson converters with spring boot and web mvc:

`HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration` creates the `stringHttpMessageConverter` and a `mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`  (with configurable object mapper) beans.
`HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration` also creates a `HttpMessageConverters` bean and takes the previously mentioned converters as a constructor param with the name "additionalConverters".  The used constructor has an add default converters flag with true value as well. It gets the default converters by instantiating a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class and calling its `getDefaultConverters` method.
That method creates a second `mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` (with a default, non configurable object mapper).
`HttpMessageConverters` concats the converters passed through the constructor with default ones from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` instance.

The `HttpMessageConverters` containing the duplicate json converter is used in example by `RestTemplateAutoConfiguration` hence by `RestTemplateBuilder`.