# Configure LocaldateTime in Spring Rest API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use Java 10 with latest Spring spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.0.RELEASE

POM configuration:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Rest Endpoint:

```
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable String id) {
        return transactionRepository
                .findById(Integer.parseInt(id))
                .map(mapper::toDTO)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
```

DTO:

```
public class PaymentTransactionsDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private String status;

    private LocalDateTime created_at;

    private String merchant;
    .... getters and setters
}
```

But when I try to return JSON data for LocalDateTime created_at I get empty result. I suppose that LocalDateTime is not properly converted into JSON value.

Can you advice how I can fix this issue?

Comment: You need to add converter and register in spring eg. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder

Comment: Can you paste official answer so I can rate it, please?

Comment: isn't your issue resolved with the converter.

Comment: do you have @EnableWebMvc in any of your springboot configuration classes? check this out _@OP_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437011/enablewebmvc-disables-jackson2objectmapperbuildercustomizer-how-to-fix/75149902#75149902

Answer (score 10):

JSON serialization is driven by Jackson's `ObjectMapper`, which I recommend configuring explicitely. For proper serialization of the Java 8 date and time objects, make sure to

- register the `JavaTimeModule`
- disable writing dates as timestamps
- setting the date format (use `StdDateFormat`)

Description of `StdDateFormat`:

> Default `DateFormat` implementation used by standard Date
>   serializers and deserializers. For serialization defaults to using an
>   **ISO-8601** compliant format (format String "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
>   and for deserialization, both **ISO-8601 and RFC-1123**.

Recommended configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector())
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat())
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    }
```

}
    }

Examples of serialized date and time objects:

- `LocalDate`: **2018-11-21**
- `LocalTime`: **11:13:13.274**
- `LocalDateTime`: **2018-11-21T11:13:13.274**
- `ZonedDateTime`: **2018-11-21T11:13:13.274+01:00**

**Edit**: standalone dependencies (already included transitively in `spring-boot-starter-web`):

- `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations`
- `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind`
- `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310`

Comment: What do you mean by `register the JavaTimeModule`? Add maven dependency?

Comment: It means the line `mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`. I edited the post to list the explicit jackson modules required, however they are already included in `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, LocalDateTime is still printed as an array

Answer (score 5):

Try using @JsonFormat on your created_at field.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

Comment: No, it's not fixing the issue.

Comment: Probably I'm applying this annotation on DTO not in JPA Entity?

Comment: You need to apply it on DTO only. You can use a workaround by taking string instead of local date time and convert your local date time into string. This is not the best approach but may be helpful.

Comment: Also you can try solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format

Answer (score 2):

My dates defined as LocalDateTime were been serializaded as an array like this:

```
"timestamp": [
    2023,
    2,
    15,
    10,
    30,
    45,
    732425200
],
```

So following the Peter Walser answer and using some code of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot) topic, here is what I did in my WebConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  // other configs

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(
        new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .dateFormat(new StdDateFormat())
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .build()));
  }

}
```

Now everything is good again:

```
"timestamp": "2023-02-15T10:32:06.5170689",
```

Try play around with some Jackson builder properties, hope it's been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add converter and register in spring eg. 
[baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder](https://baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder)

Answer (score 1):

You can type your PaymentTransactionsDTO "created_at" attribute as a String and use a converter to convert the String to LocalDate (type of the attribute created_at of your entity "PaymentTransactions")

```
@Component
public class PaymentTransactionsConverter implements Converter<PaymentTransactionsDTO, PaymentTransactions> {

    @Override
    public PaymentTransactions convert(PaymentTransactionsDTO paymentTransactionsDTO) {

        PaymentTransactions paymentTransactions = new PaymentTransactions();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

        ...

        paymentTransactions.setCreated_at(LocalDate.parse(paymentTransactionsDTO.getCreated_at(), formatter));

        return paymentTransactions;
    }
}
```