# Best option to map dates for consume REST API

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I need to consume a Rest API using Java/Spring (RestTemplate).
After doing some smoke test with Postman I see the dates fields have this structure

```
"clipStartDate": {
  "__type": "Date",
  "iso": "2010-09-14T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I tried to map this fields in my DTO using java.time.LocalDateTime.
But I'm getting a serialization exception. (org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime`)

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: there are probably at least 100 Q&A on this subject on this website, did you try searching a little?

Comment: I saw a post from 6 years ago and they are using java.util.Date. I want to know if is possible to use a class from the Java time API

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It doesn't work neigther. I got = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of START_OBJECT token;

Comment: so something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365917/configure-localdatetime-in-spring-rest-api

Comment: The plroblem is I need to define my beans thru xml. Using myModule-beans.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error you're seeing means that your `ObjectMapper` is not configured properly. In Spring Boot this comes autoconfigured out of the box, so if you use e.g Spring Boot 2.2 this error will disappear.

However if for some reason you don't have this possibility, then you need to configure an `ObjectMapper` with an additional module called `JavaTimeModule`.

```
  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    return new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
  }
```

Here's a suplementary [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper) describing how to further customize `ObjectMapper`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `java.time.Instant` and it will map properly. The format in your question is of `java.time.Instant`, So define the field as `Instant` and it should work.

Add `@JsonDeserialize(using=InstantDeserializer.class)` on top of property like following:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=InstantDeserializer.class)
private final Instant instant;
```

Comment: Hi. I'm getting the same exception org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.Instant` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.Instant` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Comment: Add `@JsonDeserialize(using=InstantDeserializer.class)` on top of the property declaration.

Comment: Can you please share the code of pom.xml and any configuration done around `ObjectMapper`? That will help better understand the situation in your case.

Comment: Hi. I'm not using Maven. This project is using ant

Comment: Can you please share versions of frameworks like Spring, Jackson and Sample/glimpse of code, if it is not still not solved?