# spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL not working when added to application.yml file in spring boot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jackson, yaml

I am trying to add the jackson annotation at the application level via application.yml file. But when I run the application, the jackson annotation is ignored and the response has the null attributes as well. Cn someone help me here? I have added the below line in my application.yml

spring.jackson:
  default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL

even after this I am seeing the response with null values.

Am I missing something or is there an issue with the version I m using? I am currently using jackson annotation version - 2.9.0

Comment: Per documentation , the value is in lower case non_null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customise the Jackson JSON mapper implicitly used by Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot)

Comment: @Gopi property value is case insensitive. both non_null and NON_NULL works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Property `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL` works with latest spring-boot version `2.5.0`.

For older versions, where the property doesn't work, you can use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation at class or field level.

Please note that field level annotation overrides the class level annotation, and class level annotation overrides the application level property.