# Spring-Boot: Jackson serialization configuration not respected

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am working with spring-boot 2.5.4 and trying to set `default-property-inclusion=non_null` globally, so that null values no longer show up in my spring web server's responses.

I have configured `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` in my project's `application.yml` as described in [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot/28324976#28324976).

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: non_null
```

Unfortunately, null-values are still included in my controller's output:

```json
{
    "enabled": true,
    "name": "foo",
    "subdomain": null,
    "tenantId": null
}
```

What works however is if I add non-null directly to my dto:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class GlobalTenantGet {

    private UUID tenantId;

    private String name;

    private String subdomain;

    private boolean enabled;
}
```

yielding

```json
{
    "enabled": true,
    "name": "foo"
}
```

as expected.

### question

Why does configuring `@JsonInclude` locally on the dto cause the null properties to disappear as expected but why does configuring `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` not have the same effect?

### additional info

#### 1. Debugging

Setting a breakpoint in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration#jacksonObjectMapper` shows, that the properties configured in `application.yaml` really made it to jackson:

[image: serializationInclusion]

#### 2. Autowiring `ObjectMapper` in the controller

I get the expected behavior when autowiring the `ObjectMapper` in my controller and serializing my object directly via `objectMapper.writeValueAsString()`.

### other ways to configure the `ObjectMapper`

These are mostly in reply to [Pawel Woroniecki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69215842/2275)'s answer

#### 1. Using @primary

I have a

```java
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        final var om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        return om;
    }
}
```

still includes null properties in the output

#### 2. `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` with `serializationInclusion`

```java
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }
}
```

still yields

```
{
    "enabled": true,
    "name": "foo",
    "subdomain": null,
    "tenantId": null
}
```

#### 3. define `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`

```java
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageMappingConverter() {
        final var om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(om);
    }
}
```

still no bueno :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems `@EnableWebMvc` is the culprit. I have a `WebMvcConfigurer` that looks like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc // <----- this is the culprit!
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .allowedOrigins("example.com")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    }

}
```

commenting out `@EnableWebMvc` allows everything to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible approaches to solve this issue and some of them are clearly explained here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper

Generally you can:

1. Override default `ObjectMapper` by creating custom `ObjectMapper` bean and marking it as `@Primary` (the simplest way but heavily impacts your application as all `ObjectMapper` instances you inject in code will use this one by default which may be good or not for you)
2. Define custom bean for `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and set proper `serializationInclusion` on this builder.
3. Register custom HTTP message converter in Spring which will use custom ObjectMapper by defining bean for `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` (constructor of this converter accepts `ObjectMapper` so you can pass properly configured mapper there)

Comment: Hello and welcome @pawel-woroniecki ! Thank you for investing time in answering my question! In the end you put me on the right path. I have added a response with what ultimately fixed my problem.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the welcome. I'm glad I could somehow help you to find the final answer