# Is it possible to create a custom Jackson objectMapper for Spring without resorting to XML?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

[It's easy to create a custom ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7854030/344286) for Spring, but the configuration requires XML. I'm trying to reduce the amount of XML configuration for things that really aren't going to change without requiring a redeploy of my entire system anyway.

So the title says it all - can I use annotations or some other non-XML method to tell Spring, "Hey, please use my custom object mapper pls"?

---

**EDIT:**

This does not appear to work

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper mapper(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
I do not believe that Spring is using *my* ObjectMapper. I have this code:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper mapper(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JodaModule mod = new JodaModule();
    mod.addSerializer(DateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<DateTime>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(DateTime dateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            System.out.println("Hi, bob");
        }
    });
    mapper.registerModule(mod);

    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    return mapper;
}
```

but when I set a breakpoint on `System.out.println("Hi, bob")` it is never called - Though I'm definitely serializing a DateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always follow the steps provided in the [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

> If you want to replace the default `ObjectMapper` completely, define a `@Bean` of that type and mark it as `@Primary`.
>
> Defining a `@Bean` of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` will allow you to customize both default `ObjectMapper` and `XmlMapper` (used in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` respectively).

So, either you define a `@Bean` with your `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    // Customize...
    return new ObjectMapper().setLocale(Locale.UK);
}
```

Or, you define a `@Bean` of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and customize the builder like this:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

    // Customize
    builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    return builder;
}
```

[This blog entry](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) describes the customization further.

In order to register beans using the `@Bean` annotation you must declare the `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class as described in the [Spring docs about Java-based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java).

Comment: I've added information to my question - I'm using the first example, but it does not appear to work. camelCase names are not changed to `camel_case`, and both `java.util.Date` and joda `DateTime` are displayed the normal way.

Comment: Is your @Configuration-class scanned at startup?

Comment: I had to add some several lines of configuration to my web.xml - on my @Configuration class and added `@ComponentScan(basePackages = `com.mystuff`)`. It wasn't loading the page before but it does now so I assume it's being scanned.

Comment: set a breakpoint in my `mapper` function - it's definitely getting hit.

Comment: Will spring automatically use my ObjectMapper to convert the object, or do I have to specify that somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug. The Spring Boot documentation says that annotating an ObjectMapper Bean with @Primary should make the Spring context use it instead of the Spring's default mapper. However, this doesn't seem to work. I have found a workaround without using XML.

```
//Since Spring won't use the custom object mapper Bean defined below for
//HTTP message conversion(eg., when a Java object is returned from a controller,
//and should be converted to json using Jackson), we must override this method
//and tell it to use a custom message converter. We configure that custom converter
//below to use our customized Object mapper.
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}

//configures the converter to use our custom ObjectMapper
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    //this line here
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
    return jsonConverter;
}


//Primary annotation tells the Spring container to use this
//mapper as the primary mapper, instead of
//the Spring's defaultly configured mapper. Primary annotation
// DOESN'T work for some reason(this is most likely a bug and will be resolved in the future.
// When resolved, this Bean will be all it takes to tell Spring to use this ObjectMapper everywhere)
// That means that there won't be a need to configure the Http message converters manually(see method above).
@Primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    configureObjectMapper(mapper);
    return mapper;
}

//configure ObjectMapper any way you'd like
//This configuration tells the ObjectMapper to 
//(de)serialize all fields(private,protected,public,..) of all objects
//and to NOT (de)serialize any properties(getters,setters).
private void configureObjectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    //properties for jackson are fields with getters and setters
    //sets all properties to NOT be serialized or deserialized
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    //tell the mapper to traverse all fields and not only default
    //default=public fields + fields with getters and setters
    //set all fields to be serialized and deserialized
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
}
```