# How to set format of string for java.time.Instant using objectMapper?

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, java-time, objectmapper

I have an entity with `java.time.Instant` for created data field:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Item {
    private String id;
    private String url;
    private Instant createdDate;
}
```

I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` to save item to Elasticsearch as JSON:

```
bulkRequestBody.append(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(item));
```

`ObjectMapper` serializes this field as an object:

```
"createdDate": {
    "epochSecond": 1502643595,
    "nano": 466000000
}
```

I was trying the annotation `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)` but it doesn't work for me.

My question is how I could serialize this field as `2010-05-30 22:15:52` string?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for answer, I have added `objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);` and  `objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules()` It does not work for me.

Comment: Have you added the module jar file to your classpath?

Comment: Sure, `compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-modules-java8', version: '2.9.0', ext: 'pom'` this one

Answer (score 160, accepted):

One solution is to use [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). Then you can add a `JavaTimeModule` to your object mapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

By default the `Instant` is serialized as the epoch value (seconds and nanoseconds in a single number):

```
{"createdDate":1502713067.720000000}
```

You can change that by setting in the object mapper:

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

This will produce the output:

```
{"createdDate":"2017-08-14T12:17:47.720Z"}
```

Both formats above are deserialized without any additional configuration.

To change the serialization format, just add a `JsonFormat` annotation to the field:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "UTC")
private Instant createdDate;
```

You need to set the timezone, otherwise the `Instant` can't be serialized properly (it throws an exception). The output will be:

```
{"createdDate":"2017-08-14 12:17:47"}
```

---

Another alternative, if you don't want to (or can't) use java8 modules, is to create a custom serializer and deserializer, using a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```
public class MyCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Instant> {

    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    @Override
    public void serialize(Instant value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String str = fmt.format(value);

        gen.writeString(str);
    }
}

public class MyCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Instant> {

    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    @Override
    public Instant deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return Instant.from(fmt.parse(p.getText()));
    }
}
```

Then you annotate the field with those custom classes:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
private Instant createdDate;
```

The output will be:

```
{"createdDate":"2017-08-14 12:17:47"}
```

---

One detail is that in the serialized string you're discarding the fraction of second (everything after the decimal point). So, when deserializing, this information can't be recovered (it'll be set to zero).

In the example above, the original `Instant` is `2017-08-14T12:17:47.720Z`, but the serialized string is `2017-08-14 12:17:47` (without the fraction of seconds), so when deserialized the resulting `Instant` is `2017-08-14T12:17:47Z` (the `.720` milliseconds are lost).

Comment: What format string would I have to use in case I would like to keep fraction of seconds? Thx.

Comment: How to disable conversion of nano sec. I do not want to send decimal number. instead just need mili second number

Comment: JsonFormat annotation didn't work for me. but the `JavaTimeModule` did..

Comment: Didn't work for me with java 8 modules and `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` false, I get the error `no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2020-08-13T10:46:16.860Z')`

Comment: For Jackson version > `2.10`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60647878/389489).

Comment: Setting the timezone on JsonFormat did the trick for me (and optional milliseconds. @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]'Z'", timezone = "UTC")

Answer (score 10):

For those looking to parse Java 8 timestamps. You need a recent version of `jackson-datatype-jsr310` in your POM and have the following module registered:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

To test this code

```
@Test
void testSeliarization() throws IOException {
    String expectedJson = "{\"parseDate\":\"2018-12-04T18:47:38.927Z\"}";
    MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo(ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-12-04T18:47:38.927Z"));

    // serialization
    assertThat(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo)).isEqualTo(expectedJson);

    // deserialization
    assertThat(objectMapper.readValue(expectedJson, MyPojo.class)).isEqualTo(pojo);
}
```

Comment: For Jackson version > `2.10`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60647878/389489).

Answer (score 7):

Here's some Kotlin code of formatting `Instant`, so it does not contain milliseconds, you can use custom date formatters

```
ObjectMapper().apply {
        val javaTimeModule = JavaTimeModule()
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(Instant::class.java, Iso8601WithoutMillisInstantSerializer())
        registerModule(javaTimeModule)
        disable(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
    }

private class Iso8601WithoutMillisInstantSerializer
        : InstantSerializer(InstantSerializer.INSTANCE, false, DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendInstant(0).toFormatter())
```

Comment: This is one of the good solution, here we don't need to edit the model class and we can customise the deserializer functionality as and when needed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And then register the modules as below :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'found this solution. But this solution seems to be deprecated

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was enough to register the JavaTimeModule:

```
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
  objectMapper.registerModule(module);

  messageObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event);
```

In the event Object I have a field of type Instant.

In the deserialization you also need to register the java time module:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

Event event = objectMapper.readValue(record.value(), Event.class);
```

Comment: the important thing here is "`new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`should be active during serialization . Otherwise, Objectmapper will use `epochSecond` and `nano` convert the Instant data type to a nested object."

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring ObjectMapper which already configured with JavaTimeModule. Just inject it from Spring context and don't use `new ObjectMapper()`.

Comment: Only applicable if `spring-web` is on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

If using Spring, and `spring-web` is on the classpath, you can create an `ObjectMapper` using the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. It registers the following commonly used modules within the method `registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable`.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule
com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
```

Some of these modules have been merged into Jackson 3; see [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8).