# Exception during deserialize java.time.Instant from redis cache

Tags: exception, redis, deserialization, java.time.instant

I keep getting following exception while reading data from cache.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.Instant` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

It started as soon as I introduced new variable of type java.time.Instant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **JsonSerializer** and **JsonDeserializer** to serialize Instant object either as milliseconds or custom text format.

For example implementation follow the answer section of [How to set format of string for java.time.Instant using objectMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662820/how-to-set-format-of-string-for-java-time-instant-using-objectmapper)