# How can I validate the format of LocalDate in test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I have the `cDate` in my model class below, and want to write a test to validate the format is as specified. The test is below (I have omitted some for brevity), but it fails with an exception (below). Originally this was a `String` type which was fine as I can use a `@Pattern(regexp = "")` but the requirement is to use `LocalDate`. When I use the correct format in the test, it correctly passes as it is being compared to the `@JsonFormat` pattern. So how can I validate the format of `LocalDate` type? I have also tried adding `throws DateTimeParseException` to the test and tried using / in the pattern.

```
  @NotNull(message = "cDate is mandatory")
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
  @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
  private LocalDate cDate;

@Test
public void shouldValidateDateFormatFailure() {
  // Given
  String test = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM-dd"));
  LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(test);
....

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20-06-04' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: you are adding test for LocalDateSerializer, right?

Comment: LocalDate.parse(test) uses default ISO date formatter. you can use LocalDate.parse(test, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM-dd")) to parse it.

Comment: I used LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(test, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM-dd")); but it passes, it should fail as its not matching whats defined in @JsonFormat

Comment: You can use javax-validation-api, It will help you to pass some invalid values. And try to use String instead of `localdate`

Answer (score 1):

LocalDate is part of the Java 8 time packages.
You need jackson-modules-java8 or jackson-datatype-jsr310 in your dependencies and register it to your Jackson ObjectMapper.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
```

Related answer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662820/how-to-set-format-of-string-for-java-time-instant-using-objectmapper)