# How to map an Angular 10 client Date field in a DTO that is pushed to a Spring Boot rest API where the target field is an 'Instant"

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to work out how to format a Typescript 'Date' field that is part of a DTO that is sent from my Angular 10 client to a Spring Boot rest service where the matching Sprint Boot field is of Java type 'Instant'.

On the Angular side if I use....

```
return aDate.toISOString();
```

.. .then on the Spring Boot side I'm getting an error...

> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant`
> from String ""2021-02-26T15:51:35.505Z"":

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662820/how-to-set-format-of-string-for-java-time-instant-using-objectmapper

Comment: That fixed it Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set format of string for java.time.Instant using objectMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662820/how-to-set-format-of-string-for-java-time-instant-using-objectmapper)