# Spring Web - How to format `Instant` in a specific way

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am developing a REST controller in Spring. One of the requirements is to be able to handle dates only in ISO-8601 format.

I'm using `Instant` for this purpose. When used in request DTOs, it handles incoming dates perfectly. But when used in response DTOs, the output format needs a little change.

The date in json output looks like this:
`2022-02-03T15:00:00Z`

But it should look like this:
`2022-02-03T15:00:00.000Z`

**I want to specify how `RestController` formats `Instant`.** To that end, I can think of several solutions.

1. Is there a way to override how `RestController` converts a specific class to string? Perhaps in the same way that exception handling is done (with `@ExceptionHandler`).
2. Is there a way to intercept the DTO after it gets converted to json? Before getting sent off to the client, that is.
3. Is there a way to simply annotate the return value of the rest controller's method to achieve the desired format?

Comment: Did you try `@JsonFormat(pattern=“yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ”)` on your DTO?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use [JavaTimeModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8#jackson-2x). I defined the `ObjectMapper` bean configuration for Spring's DI, and then used the `@JsonFormat` annotation on the `Instant` field of the DTO.

One thing to note is that when using the `pattern` field of `@JsonFormat`, the `timezone` field becomes mandatory for some reason. Even setting the `time-zone` in `application.properties` doesn't work. I set `timezone = "0"`, as I need to use UTC dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jackson to serialize and deserialize JSON data in you Spring Boot project, I would like to suggest you use LocalDate/LocalDateTime types for your needs. Then, you can edit your application.properties and add here such row:

```
jackson.date-format=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat
```

Also, you need to have a Maven/Gradle dependency [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)

Probably, it will also work with Instant type, but I didn't test it.

Also, if you use your own ObjectMapper (not autoconfigured by Spring) you need to add Jackson Module to it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662820/how-to-set-format-of-string-for-java-time-instant-using-objectmapper) is an explanation in another question.