# Enable DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION feature for Jackson in Spring using XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Short question:

is it possible to enable `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` Jackson feature (e.g. set it to `true`) in Spring using **XML** configuration **only**?

In other words I want to do what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842962/1479414 but without creating java class, but configure it inside XML only.

It is possible to do?

Comment: Did you have the chance to test the approach described in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39873175/1426227)?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Yes, thank you. it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring 3.2, you could use [`Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.html). Something like:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="defaultViewInclusion" value="true"/>
</bean>
```