# Using @JsonView with Spring Hateoas

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

If I use `@JsonView` on a POJO and on a controller in Spring, my HATEOAS links are hidden. I can understand why this happens, because the `_links` property isn't annotated with the correct view class, but it's not the behaviour I need in this case. Is there a way to always include the `_links` property, regardless of using a view class or not?

My POJO looks something like:

```
@Entity(name = "groups")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "groups_groupid_seq", sequenceName = "groups_groupid_seq")
public class Group extends ResourceSupport {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "groups_groupid_seq")
    @JsonView(Views.Summary.class)
    private long groupID;

    @JsonView(Views.Full.class)
    private String name;

    /*
        Getters & setters ...
     */
}
```

And my controller looks something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/group")
@ExposesResourceFor(Group.class)
public class GroupApiController {
    @JsonView(Views.Summary.class)
    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable getPermittedGroups(
            Authentication authentication) {
        // load groups...
    }
}
```

My HATEOAS configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableEntityLinks
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class HateoasConfig {
    //
}
```

I don't have to use `@JsonView`, so I'm happy to use an alternative. But I do need to be able to return different views on the same class, from different controller methods, otherwise I could use `@JsonIgnore`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to always include the _links property, regardless of
>   using a view class or not?

**Using Spring Boot**
Set the spring jackson mapper configuration
`spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true`
Within your application.properties

**Using Spring @Configuration Classes**
This topic is well covered in ["Configuring Object Mapper in Spring"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842962/1333618)

**However**, there are currently issues in particular with HATEOAS that prevent this from working. In particular is the open ticket ["Support for HATEOAS-Links in Json-Views"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/pull/387)