# How can I get an ObjectMapper instance in Spring Boot without inheriting from spring-boot-starter-web?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm playing around with Spring Boot 2.0.0M2, trying to create a CLI application, not a web one. My problem is that even including

```
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
```

in my build, ObjectMapper is not created by Boot because

```
Bean method 'jacksonObjectMapper' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder'
```

What's the best practice when you want to have Spring Boot instance and configure Jackson but don't want to start a web server?

Comment: Can't you just add the jar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring)

Comment: Thing is, Spring Boot autoconfigures the `ObjectMapper` and it can be tuned by several well documented configuration properties. If I create the `ObjectMapper` as the other question propose, all of this should be done by hand, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Spring boot without web starter does not initializes ObjectMapper. It is silly, they intend you will not use JSON outside of HTTP: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10031

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add `spring-boot-starter-json` if you want to avoid to include the full web stack (since Spring Boot v.2.0.0M4).

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Is the optimal solution going forward?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just initialize it yourself.

```
@Bean
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Comment: My problem is, as I said in a previous comment, that Spring Boot autoconfigures `ObjectMapper` with several well documented configuration properties. If I instance it by my self, all of this tuning is lost, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Yes you need to do it by hand, but it is not that hard, and looking at the source code of `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` it doesn't seem to set any default values. It does auto detect some well-known modules but adding them by hand is not that hard. If you really want to, you could copy the java into your code, it is ASL2, but I would just use my own object wrapper.

Comment: But this should be work just by using @Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper. If we initialize it by ourselves, this wouldn't be a smart solution right?

Answer (score 2):

You can try and JUST add `org.springframework:spring-web` dependency as that class is located in it.

Comment: But if this is just a java application rather than web application, what should I do?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10031 has some background and justification for this.