# Configure Objectmapper used by Java AWS Lambda

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to develop an AWS Lambda function that is triggered by events from SQS.

I am using the *spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws* (version 1.0.0.RELEASE) and in specifically a *SpringBootRequestHandler*.

However, the ObjectMapper that is being used is case-sensitive and therefore failing to successful convert the Json coming from SQS.

SQS publishes the following Json and it is the **Records** field in particular that I'm having the problem with.

```
    {
  "Records": [
    {
      "body": "Hello from SQS!",
      "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle",
      "md5OfBody": "7b270e59b47ff90a553787216d55d91d",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:123456789012:MyQueue",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
      "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
      "attributes": {
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001",
        "SenderId": "123456789012",
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "1523232000000"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the suggestions in this question, but to no avail. [Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring)

In my POJO, I've also added the below annotation but it isn't working either whilst it would outside of Lambda.

```
@JsonProperty("Records")
private List<SqsRecord> Records;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

My Lambda handler is defined as:

```
public class SqsEventHandler extends SpringBootRequestHandler<SqsEvent, String> {}
```

The POJO defined as:

```
public class SqsEvent {

@JsonProperty("Records")
private List<SqsRecord> records;

@Data
public class SqsRecord {
    private String body;
    private String receiptHandle;
    private String md5OfBody;
    private String eventSourceARN;
    private String eventSource;
    private String awsRegion;
    private String messageId;
}
```

}

I expect the Json from the sample message to be able to be read in by the ObjectMapper, but the field "records" is null.

Comment: Define "doesn't work", precisely. Post the relevant code, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead, precisely.

Comment: I've updated the original question with more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this issue solved in a more simple manner.

Referencing https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-stream.html and in specific

> if Lambda's serialization approach does not meet your needs, you can use the byte stream implementation

I am now using the SpringBootStreamHandler directly and I have created an ObjectMapper instance with my required configuration options in my Spring Configuration class as:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return mapper;
}
```

Comment: any examples in using SpringBootStreamHandler?

Comment: Can you provide a sample on how you used SpringBootStreamHandler directly?

Comment: Not ideal if you don't want case insensitivity globally across Spring though.

Answer (score 2):

we've got this problem with a lot of AWS services.
You must define a new mapper like this :

SQSMixin :

```
 private static interface SQSEventMixin {
    public static final String ATTRIBUTES = "attributes";
    public static final String AWS_REGION = "awsRegion";
    public static final String BODY = "body";
    public static final String EVENT_SOURCE = "eventSource";
    public static final String EVENT_SOURCE_ARN = "eventSourceARN";
    public static final String MD5_OF_BOBY = "md5OfBody";
    public static final String MD5_OF_MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTES = "md5OfMessageAttributes";
    public static final String MESSAGE_ID = "messageId";
    public static final String RECEIPT_HANDLE = "receiptHandle";

    @JsonProperty(value = "Records")
    public List<?> getRecords();

    static interface MessageMixin {
        @JsonProperty(ATTRIBUTES)
        public String getAttributes();

        @JsonProperty(ATTRIBUTES)
        public void setAttributes(String attributes);

        @JsonProperty(AWS_REGION)
        public String getAwsRegion();

        @JsonProperty(AWS_REGION)
        public void setAwsRegion(String awsRegion);

        @JsonProperty(BODY)
        public Object getBody();

        @JsonProperty(BODY)
        public void setBody(Object body);

        @JsonProperty(EVENT_SOURCE)
        public String getEventSource();

        @JsonProperty(EVENT_SOURCE)
        public void setEventSource(String eventSource);

        @JsonProperty(EVENT_SOURCE_ARN)
        public String getEventSourceArn();

        @JsonProperty(EVENT_SOURCE_ARN)
        public void setEventSourceArn(String eventSourceArn);

        @JsonProperty(MD5_OF_BOBY)
        public String getMd5OfBody();

        @JsonProperty(MD5_OF_BOBY)
        public void setMd5OfBody(String md5OfBody);

        @JsonProperty(MD5_OF_MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTES)
        public String getMd5OfMessageAttributes();

        @JsonProperty(MD5_OF_MESSAGE_ATTRIBUTES)
        public void setMd5OfMessageAttributes(String md5OfMessageAttributes);

        @JsonProperty(MESSAGE_ID)
        public String getMessageId();

        @JsonProperty(MESSAGE_ID)
        public void setMessageId(String messageId);

        @JsonProperty(RECEIPT_HANDLE)
        public String getReceiptHandle();

        @JsonProperty(RECEIPT_HANDLE)
        public void setReceiptHandle(String receiptHandle);
    }
}
```

A Strategy for record :

```
private static class UpperCaseRecordsPropertyNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String translate(String propertyName) {
        if (propertyName.equals("records")) {
            return "Records";
        }
        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

Formatter for Date :

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()
        .withZone(new FixedDateTimeZone("GMT", "GMT", 0, 0));

private static class DateTimeMapperModule extends SimpleModule {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DateTimeMapperModule() {
        super("DateTimeMapperModule");

        super.addSerializer(DateTime.class, new DateTimeSerializer());
        super.addDeserializer(DateTime.class, new DateTimeDeserializer());
    }
}

private static class DateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

        gen.writeString(dateTimeFormatter.print(value));
    }
}

private static class DateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DateTime> {

    @Override
    public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {

        return dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(parser.getText());
    }
}
```

And declare your mapper :

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new UpperCaseRecordsPropertyNamingStrategy());
    mapper.registerModule(new DateTimeMapperModule());
    mapper.addMixIn(SQSMessage.class, SQSEventMixin.MessageMixin.class);
    SQSEvent request = mapper.convertValue(inputObject, SQSEvent.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already an official library that is supporting this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/testing-aws-lambda-functions-written-in-java/

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-tests</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also have surefire in your plugins:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Example:

```
SQSEvent input = EventLoader.loadEvent("/sqsEvent.json", SQSEvent.class);
```