# Mapping query results into object for REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring Framework and having troubles retrieving a native query result from my application. The application is supposed to retrieve some specific data from my PostgreSQL database and expose it as a REST resource. However, it seems not to be able to map the query results into the entity object i defined. The object is defined the same way the database is made: i've also used the same entity for the insert operation on my logger application.

I've created an **Entity** class:

```
package com.umeter.rest;

import ...

@Entity
@Table(name="dati_impianti")
public class DatiImpiantoEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_lettura;

    @Column(name="sigla_impianto")
    private String sigla_impianto;
    @Column(name="timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;
    @Column(name="lettura")
    private Float lettura;
    @Column(name="stato")
    private Integer stato;

    public Integer getId_lettura() {
        return id_lettura;
    }

    public void setId_lettura(Integer id_lettura) {
        this.id_lettura = id_lettura;
    }

    public String getSigla_impianto() {
        return sigla_impianto;
    }

//other Getters and Setters
```

A **Repository** class (with a random nativequery just to try it out).

*EDIT: Yes, using the native query is needed because i will be using some native functionality from postgresql that are not available through the normal CRUD methods available. However, this seems not to be the issue as i tried with a "findAll()" method just to get the exact same [null] output*

```
package com.umeter.rest;

import ...

@Repository
public interface DatiRepository extends CrudRepository<DatiImpiantoEntity, Integer> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * from dati_impianti LIMIT 10")
    public List<DatiImpiantoEntity> getIstantanea();
}
```

And a **REST Controller**:

```
package com.umeter.rest;

import ...

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api")
public class DatiRestController {

    @Autowired
    private DatiRepository datiRepository;


    @GetMapping(path="/istantanea")
        public @ResponseBody List<DatiImpiantoEntity> getIstantanea() {
            return datiRepository.getIstantanea();
    }
}
```

However, the result i'm getting is a list of null values (i suppose Spring isn't able to map the query results into my Entity object):

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

I'm getting an output when i set the method with a generic "Object" return type (which is excluding a database connection or query problem). However, what i get is not a correct Json output format, and i know this is now how it's supposed to be:

```
[["MF1","2019-10-11T10:24:23.917+0000",3.814,6,null],["MF1","2019-10-11T10:24:33.867+0000",3.814,6,null],["MF1","2019-10-11T10:24:43.920+0000",3.814,6,null],["MF1","2019-10-11T10:24:53.884+0000",3.814,6,null],["MF1","2019-10-11T10:25:03.864+0000",3.814,6,null],["MF1","2019-10-11T10:25:13.869+0000",3.814,6,null],["MF1","2019-10-11T10:25:23.872+0000",3.814,6,null],["MF1","2019-11-08T13:17:35.175+0000",5511.1,0,null],["MF2","2019-11-08T13:17:35.174+0000",6567.025,0,null],["MF1","2019-11-08T13:25:25.655+0000",5548.027,0,null]]
```

For completeness purposes, i attach a picture of the database data structure (the id seems not to be really used but it was required by Spring for the insertion process):
[image: Database Structure]

Comment: Have you configured a JSON object mapper? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842962/1600632)?

Comment: @HariharDas i haven't tried thoroughly (and it's not included on my current sources), but this does not seem to be an issue considering that it's working without on Spring docs examples. I can give it another try, but when i did, i only got the same "null" outputs but with {} brackets instead

Comment: Can you please also override the `toString` method of your `DatiImpiantoEntity`? e.g. return the `timestamp` field from your overridden `toString` method.

Comment: I did that on a previous test, with no results. Also correct me if i am wrong, but i suppose what we want it's not a string representation of the "class" but more like a mapping into the object (where the json output will be made of the toString method from all the fields and not from the class itself)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to see if it was a problem with logging to the console. But seems like you added the output of the controller method to the question. Which is indeed a list of null values.

Comment: One more thing. Do you have an empty constructor in your entity class?

Comment: I had the constructor, yes, with no changing: i tried both with the empty constructor and with a full constructor with all variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204878/discussion-between-harihar-das-and-mastarius).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database table `dati_impianti` has null id value for all records. This will not work with `CrudRepository`. The `id` field must have unique values across all records.

Comment: Good finding nice answer

Comment: Hi, thanks! Did you try already? I will have a look at home and see if this is the reason

Comment: Yes I have tried a similar table and repository as yours. I got similar results. But with unique id values I got expected results.

Comment: Thank you @HariharDas, i confirm you this was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the entity object rather using native query

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * from dati_impianti LIMIT 10")
    public List<DatiImpiantoEntity> getIstantanea();
```

replace this with

```
@Query("SELECT * from DatiImpiantoEntity LIMIT 10")
    public List<DatiImpiantoEntity> getIstantanea();
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not seem to work (it gives a compile-time error because of the query validation)

Comment: Ok, then try changing the query like  
`SELECT d from DatiImpiantoEntity d LIMIT 10`     i mean to use aliases. You can refer [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-introduction-to-query-methods/)