# Understand initialization time behaviour of mvc:annotation-driven

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to debug an issue with `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` initialization and I have come to a conclusion by searching the Web that it is getting initialized from `mvc:annotation-driven` xml entry. Can anyone explain me briefly, how this initialization works i.e. what happens when the parser parses `mvc:annotation-driven`? Or point me to the code that does it and I will trace it through.

Some more context on this:

I was trying to get RequestMappingHandlerAdapter from the context via autowire but could not. It gave me:

```
No matching bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter]
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Found this thread, but the solution does not does not work: [Spring, Jackson and Customization (e.g. CustomDeserializer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591291/spring-jackson-and-customization-e-g-customdeserializer/11805794#11805794)

I am using: Spring 3.1.3

This is what my servlet xml file looks like ...

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Thanks,
Parth

Comment: It just hit me that the order of mvc:annotation-driven config was wrong. I reversed it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would cause either the [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) or [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html) to search for the annotated classes and create/graph them.  One way to figure things out would be to make a bean that throws a RuntimeException in its default constructor and see what the stack trace looks like.