# Different JSON configuration in a Spring application for REST and Ajax serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

In a Spring application I have added a custom JSON serializer which is applied to a field with thte tag:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=MySerializer.class)
```

And the MySerializer serializer (whcihc extends from JsonSerializer) has a method which looks like:

```
@Override
public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{ 
    //some logic
}
```

It works and execute the logic when the application generates json in the methods annotated with @ResponseBody but it also executes the same logic when the application uses a webservice with JSON. I'd like to set up different configurations for the RestTemplate serialization and for @ResponseBody, or at least, being able to differenciate in the serializate method whether we are in a @ResponseBody case or in a RestTemplate one.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Mix-in Annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature. For example, your `POJO` classes could look like that:

```
class Root {

    private Data data;

    // getters/setters
}

class Data {

    private String name;

    // getters/setters
}
```

Now, you have to create `MixIn` interface:

```
interface RootMixIn {

    @JsonSerialize(using = DataSerializer.class)
    Data getData();
}
```

Imagine, that custom serializer looks like this:

```
class DataSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Data> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Data data, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeFieldName("name_property");
        generator.writeString(data.getName() + " XXX");
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Finally, you have to create two `ObjectMapper`'s. Simple usage:

```
Data data = new Data();
data.setName("Tom");

Root root = new Root();
root.setData(data);

ObjectMapper mapperWithMixIn = new ObjectMapper();
mapperWithMixIn.addMixInAnnotations(Root.class, RootMixIn.class);

ObjectMapper mapperDefault = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println("With MIX-IN");
System.out.println(mapperWithMixIn.writeValueAsString(root));

System.out.println("Default");
System.out.println(mapperDefault.writeValueAsString(root));
```

Above script prints:

```
With MIX-IN
{"data":{"name_property":"Tom XXX"}}
Default
{"data":{"name":"Tom"}}
```

As you can see, `ObjectMapper` with `MixIn` you can use in request handlers, and default `ObjectMapper` you can use in RestTemplate.

## Update 1

`Spring` creates default `ObjectMapper` bean and uses it to serialize and deserialize request's data. You have to find and override this default bean. How to do it? Please, see below links:

- [Spring, Jackson and Customization (e.g. CustomDeserializer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591291/spring-jackson-and-customization-e-g-customdeserializer).
- [How to customise the Jackson JSON mapper in Spring Web MVC](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html).

This overridden bean should look like `mapperWithMixIn` in my above example.

Secondly, you have to create new `ObjectMapper` bean and inject this bean to all RestTemplate-s and use this bean in these classes as a serializer/deserializer.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I configure a different object mapper for RestTemplate from the one used in @ResponseBody in Spring?

Comment: In your question your said that you want to set up two different configurations. Why you want to use one `ObjectMapper` to create another? Could you give me more information because I do not understand your question.

Comment: I need 2 different json formats for 2 different cases, one for Ajax requests and another for invoking Rest services. and both jsons can use the same class. That's why I need 2 different ObjectMapper configurations in the same spring application. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope that now it looks much better and you will be able to find your solution.