# How to ignore Jackson annotations?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got two classes:

```
public class Bar {
    private String identifier;
    private String otherStuff;

    public Bar(){}

    public Bar(String identifier, String otherStuff) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.otherStuff = otherStuff;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

and

```
public class Foo {
    private String foo;

    @JsonSerialize(using=BarsMapSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using=BarsMapDeserializer.class)
    private Map<String, Bar> barsMap;

    public Foo(){}
    public Foo(String foo, Map<String, Bar> barsMap) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.barsMap = barsMap;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

When I sserialize **Foo** with code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Bar> barsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    barsMap.put("b1", new Bar("bar1", "nevermind1"));
    barsMap.put("b2", new Bar("bar2", "nevermind2"));
    barsMap.put("b3", new Bar("bar3", "nevermind3"));
    Foo foo = new Foo("foo", barsMap);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
}
```

the otput is:

```
{"foo":"foo","barsMap":{"b1":"bar1","b2":"bar2","b3":"bar3"}}
```

For most cases it's ok, but in some cases I want to have full **Bar** object in my json, like bellow:

```
{"foo":"foo","barsMap":{"b1":{"identifier":"bar1", "otherStuff":"nevermind1"},"b2":{"identifier":"bar2", "otherStuff":"nevermind2"},"b3":{"identifier":"bar3", "otherStuff":nevermind3"}}}
```

Is it possible to achieve this without writing custom serializer? 
I know that I can add annotation using mix-in mechanism, but basically I need to ignore existing one in some cases.

Comment: You can use MixIn mechanism and use two different `ObjectMapper`s. One   `ObjectMapper` you will use in situation when you need this custom serializer and second `ObjectMapper` you can use when you do not need it. Please, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691765/different-json-configuration-in-a-spring-application-for-rest-and-ajax-serializa/22701578

Comment: @MichałZiober In most cases I need custom serializer, that's why annotations are in my `Foo` class. I've tried Mixin mechanism and I could add some serializer with it, but I need to ignore existing one.

Comment: I understand the problem. Mainly you want to serialize this class using custom serializer but sometimes you want to serialize it using default serializer. If yes, you have only one solution: you have to create two `ObjectMapper`s objects and in first enable custom serializer (using MixIn feature), in second you shouldn't do that. You can also try to use `MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS` feature. In one `ObjectMapper` you can enable it and this object should not read annotations, so custom serializer will not be used.

Comment: What is the status of your problem? Did you solve it?

Comment: @MichałZiober I've resolved my problem using mix-in mechanism as You suggested. But I did it in different way. You can check my answer. Thank You for helping me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please upvote my answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691765/different-json-configuration-in-a-spring-application-for-rest-and-ajax-serializa/22701578 question if it was helpfull for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved my problem using mix-in mechanism.

```
public interface FooMixin {
    @JsonSerialize
    Map<String, Bar> getBarsMap();
    @JsonDeserialize
    void setBarsMap(Map<String, Bar> barsMap);
}
```

With this interface mixed in, class `Foo` is serialized as with default serializer.
As You can see You need to add `JsonSerialize` / `JsonDeserialize` annotations without specify any class.

Below code shows usage of this interface:

```
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Foo.class, FooMixin.class);
jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```