# CurrencyUnit of javamoney can't be used as class of a field and deserialized by Jackson due InvalidDefinitionException

Tags: java, jackson, java-money

I have a pojo that has a field of type `CurrencyUnit` from the javamoney library. When I marshall this pojo Jackson throws an exception. I remember this exception when I did not define any default constructor. But in this case I can not maintain the `CurrencyUnit` class since it's coming from a dependency. How can I still make this work?

**Exception:**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.money.CurrencyUnit` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information\n at
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write a custom serialiser/deserialiser for each type from `javax.money` package you want to use or register already created module. For example: [jackson-datatype-money](https://github.com/zalando/jackson-datatype-money).

You need to add [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.zalando/jackson-datatype-money/1.3.0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-money</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Simple example how to use:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.zalando.jackson.datatype.money.MoneyModule;

import javax.money.CurrencyUnit;
import javax.money.Monetary;

public class JsonMoneyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(new MoneyModule());

        CurrencyUnit cu = Monetary.getCurrency("USD");
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(cu);
        System.out.println(json);

        CurrencyUnit unit = mapper.readValue(json, CurrencyUnit.class);
        System.out.println(unit);
    }
}
```

above code prints:

```
"USD"
USD
```

Comment: is there a way to add this automatically? Spring is using jackson when returning objects of request mapping methods for example. There is no explicit use of `ObjectMapper`

Comment: @xetra11, try to add this library on classpath and maybe `Spring`'s `ObjectMapper` builder will find and register it automatically. It depends from version of `Spring` and how you set up your app. If it not will be registered automatically take a look on online resources: [Consume & Produce XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184442/springboot-consume-produce-xml-with-a-custom-serializer-deserializer), [Register a custom Jackson ObjectMapper using Spring Javaconfig](http://www.jworks.nl/2013/08/21/register-a-custom-jackson-objectmapper-using-spring-javaconfig/)

Comment: @xetra11, moreover take a look at [Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring), [Different JSON configuration in a Spring application for REST and Ajax serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691765/different-json-configuration-in-a-spring-application-for-rest-and-ajax-serializa), [Spring, Jackson and Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591291/spring-jackson-and-customization-e-g-customdeserializer), [custom jackson](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/jackson_custom.html)